# How to add an absolute element in a NativeScript page

Tags: layout, plugins, nativescript

I want to be able to just place a View component (plugin) into the page through code and have it appear at some X\Y on the page... but I'm a bit stumped.

Any attempt to add via page.content kinda adds it to the layout\render pass so it occupies space.

So this would get injected into "any" page at "any" time, I have no control over the markup this would be used in (know what I mean?) There is no XML for it and unfortunately the answer can't just be wrap everything in an AbsoluteLayout because one can't mandate that on users apps\layouts.

Thoughts, even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically the simplest way to do this is to dynamically and be fully cross platform compatible is to create a AbsoluteLayout item in your JavaScript code, and dynamically insert your item and the AL into the page container.

Code would be something like this:

```
var AbsoluteLayout = require('ui/layouts/absolute-layout').AbsoluteLayout;
var myAL = new AbsoluteLayout();
var myItem = new myPluginItem();

// Set you left, right, top, bottom coords.
myItem.top = x;

// Add our item to the AbsoluteItem
myAL.addChild(myItem);

var frame = require('ui/frame');
var page = frame.topmost().currentPage;
var LayoutBase = require('ui/layouts/layout-base').LayoutBase;

page._eachChildView(function(view) {
  if (view instanceof LayoutBase) {
     view.addChild(myAL); 
     return false;
  } 
  return true;
});
```

However, if you don't want to do this the really simple way; the only other way is to actually go a bit lower level.  You can natively access the iOS view controller (page._ios.view) and the android view (page._nativeView), and then manually add it to the view by using things like addView (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewManager.html) or addSubview (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/).

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add you can set the Top and Left properties in TypeScript  by importing AbsoluteLayout like so

`import {AbsoluteLayout} from 'ui/layouts/absolute-layout';`

and then using the exposed functions setLeft or setTop

`AbsoluteLayout.setLeft(YourItem, LeftValue);`
or
`AbsoluteLayout.setTop(YourItem, TopValue);`